# Java Displaying different objects

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, object, jframe

I would like display different pictures in a JFrame (in a random order). I am using Threads in the application as the display will need to be constantly updated.

```
   public class CarsMain extends JFrame implements Runnable {
       Random rand = new Random();

    //the main thread
    Thread thread;
    BufferedImage backbuffer;
    Cars cars;
    Car1 car1;
    //set map of the cars array
    private int Width = 10;
    private int Height = 100;
    int[][] map=new int[Width][Height];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CarsMain();
    }    

    public CarsMain() {
        super("Cars");
        setSize(500,400);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

    }



    //thread run event
    public void run() {

        Thread current = Thread.currentThread();

        while (current == thread) {
            try { Thread.sleep(0); }
            catch(InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }


           genmap();
        }
    }

       //Fills map[][] with random numbers (id's)
    private void genmap() {

        for (int i = 0; i<10;i++){      
            for (int j = 0; j<20; j++){     
        map[i][j] = rand.nextInt(5);

                }
            }

    }


    //JFrame paint event
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(backbuffer, 0, 0, this);
        for (int i = 0;i<600;i+=128){
            for(int j=30; j<500;j+=128){
                          //this is the part i am stuck on
                                // v this is just put here to test that display
                g.drawImage(cars.Car1.getpic(),i, j, this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
    public class Cars{

    public  Image pic;
    public int carid;
    public Cars carList[]= new Cars[10];




    public Cars(int i){

        carid = i;

    }

    public Image getpic(){
        return pic;

    }

    public void setpic(Image pic){
        this.pic = pic;
    }

    public int getCarid(int i){
        return Carid;
    }

    public static final Cars car0 =  new car0(1);
    public static final Cars Car1 = new car1(2);
    public static final Cars Car2  = new car2(3);
    public static final Cars Car3 = new car3(4);
    public static final Cars Car4 = new car4(5);

}
```

(each of the car# classes extends the Cars class so i can override things later) 
What i Tried to do was create a multidimensional array (genmap()) which was filled with random numbers (which works fine(also is there a way i can only run this once in the thread?)), these random numbers would correlate to the car id. Then display thee corresponding car picture to the screen using the ID, this is where I am stuck.

I have tried various ways but it usually turns out that 'pic' needs to be static (which it can't be, otherwise it would only show car4's image)

I know i could use if statements, but would really like to use the id directly, so it is easy to add new cars later on(just make the new object in the Cars class), does anybody have any idea?

Comment: What is the purpose of the sleep(0)? What I would do is create a list of all you cars, pass it to the JFRame, then the JFrame picks randomly cars in that list and paints them. Not sure I understood what your exact objective is.

Comment: terrific code! why don't you use containers, to begin with? you declare `int[][] map=new int[Width][Height];` then in the loop you are using arbitrary integers... and so on

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. 3) Please learn common [Java nomenclature](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to go through your code in detail - the general approach should be:

- Use a `javax.swing.Timer` to update the picture periodically
- use `Random.nextInt(n+1)` to choose a picture from a set of `n` pictures
- keep the pictures (or just their File or URL) in a List or array

  - load the chosen image from the File/URL if needed
- tell the GUI to repaint
- the GUI should get the current image and paint it

Answer (score 0):

You can not access a image that has not yet being created.
Static elements are created at startup. But your picture is created when Cars is created.

Create each car in your CarsMain class and add them to the array you have in Cars. Then write a getter and use it.

I think what you are doing here is highly discouraged.
And your structure is horrible.